# Bash auto increment in operation

Tags: bash, grep, sh, ps

Please explain this problem with incrementing value, we have next file named test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

ps aux | grep test.sh -c
echo $(ps aux | grep test.sh -c)
```

and then run it

```
$ ./test.sh
2
3
```

I know there is two lines after grep slice (1 with test.sh, 2 with grep), why 3 come in? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `3` in the second case because the second command `$(...)` (i.e. *command substitution*) executes in a **subshell**.

From the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Execution-Environment.html#Command-Execution-Environment):

> Command substitution, commands grouped with parentheses, and
>   asynchronous commands are invoked in a subshell environment that is a
>   duplicate of the shell environment, ...